# React Native Navigation Go Back two screen in another Navigators

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am not good at English. Please understand.

I am going to perform the action of the right picture in the navigation system with the structure such as the bottom left picture.

[My Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQyU2.png)

I tried StackActions.pop (2). However, it only returned to Screen A and was useless.

Is there a way to go back two screens or go back to the middle of the previous history list?

Thank you.

Comment: + My environment is react native : 0.65.1 / @react-natvigation/native-stack 6.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

When moving from A to B, move to the next code and run goBack in B.

```
navigation.reset({routes: [{name: 'ScreenB'}]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go to back to A Screen through---`this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenA');`